# how to iterate in snap framework without cabal install

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I love the snap framework but I hate running 'cabal install' with each iteration (minor code change) I want to try out.

Is there an alternative for rapid iteration?

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate" and "iteration" here? Do you mean "upgrade"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with

```
cabal install --reinstall -fhint snap
```

Then, for your project:

```
cabal clean
cabal configure -fdevelopment
cabal build
./dist/build/projname/projname
```

You shouldn't ever use `cabal install` for binaries that you don't want to be able to execute from arbitrary locations, anyway.  You should be using `cabal build` for things you only want to run locally.

You will need to run `cabal build` and start the program again when you change Main.hs or your project's .cabal file.

If you have any further questions, comment - I'm the guy who implemented this functionality for 
Snap.

Comment: Also, if you didn't build your app with development mode, you can reload the app manually with something like `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reload`.  This is available even if you didn't build your app with development mode.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/snap_framework/4lbb3VvGD-U for a recent discussion.

Comment: As of snap 0.9 you do not need to reinstall snap with `-fhint`

Answer (score 2):

Yesod provides `yesod devel` which automatically reloads code changes. I am not aware of a comparable capability in snap, but it is highly likely that they can reuse much of the Yesod code that does this.

Given the existence of [Snap.Loader.Devel](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.8.0.2/doc/html/Snap-Loader-Devel.html) I'm guessing they might already provide something like what you are asking for, but I can't find the documentation on how to use it. The FAQ question [How do I run my app in development mode](http://snapframework.com/faq#how-do-i-run-my-app-in-development-mode) still requires a `cabal install`; it's unclear from the docs whether you only need to do this once, or every time the code changes.